# Jetty invalidating the session after few requests while running an integration test

Tags: embedded-jetty, jetty-9

Hi I am trying to run integration test cases for my application on jetty 9.4.10, I am making requests to the server using an apache Http Client, passing sessionId as an header to the request. In some of the test cases i observe that after 10-11 successful requests, server is setting the response status as 303 to all the consecutive requests following them, as a result requests to the server are not successful and tests fail. But after 11 requests if i get a new sessionId and try executing the requests in tests, they all pass. I don't understand this behavior of jetty, Am i missing something in the configuration? Is there something to configure for maximum number of requests per minute in a current session? I have been troubleshooting this issue since a week, But I didn't get any lead.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no component in Jetty that will produce a 303 status code response.

Check your 3rd party libraries to see where that is coming from.

Comment: Well this doesn’t happen if I run my tests on a different server. For instance, if I run the same test case against weblogic server they all pass! Is there something like particular version of httpclient recommended for jetty?

Comment: Jetty is a Web Servlet container.  Weblogic is a JEE container.  That is like comparing a Dodge Ram SRT10 and a Caterpillar 797; both are trucks, but that's about where the similarity ends.   It could be that one of your 3rd party libraries is expecting something JEE that Weblogic provides with its huge JEE featureset.